# Composing complex Laravel eloquent where statement

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I need to execute the following MySQL query using Laravel Eloquent ORM:

```
select * from `events`
where `app_id` = 1
   and ((`startDate` < now() and endDate is null) or (`endDate` < now())) 
order by `startDate` desc
```

My best try so far:

```
Event::where('app_id', '=', 1) 
    -> where(function ($query) {
        $query -> where([['startDate', '<', Carbon::now() -> toDateTimeString()]) -> whereNull('endDate');
}) -> orWhere([['endDate', '<', Carbon::now() -> toDateTimeString()]])
-> orderBy('startDate', 'desc') -> get();
```

Which is not exactly what I want as it results in:

```
select * from `events`
where `app_id` = 1
   and (`startDate` < now() and endDate is null) or (`endDate` < now()) 
order by `startDate` desc
```

(Missing extra parentheses in the second compound where condition).

Any idea? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You'll need to add another where closure for `\`startDate\` < now() and endDate is null`

Comment: While you at it also rename `startDate` to `start_date` to conform same style as rest of the database like `app_id`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the task:

```
Event::where('app_id', '=', 1) 
->where(function ($q) {
    $q->where(function($query){
          $query->where('startDate', '<', Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString())->whereNull('endDate');
     })->orWhere('endDate', '<', Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString());
})
->orderBy('startDate', 'desc') -> get();
```